# How to follow JavaScript redirects in background?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control, webclient

I need to load a webpage, but I need the redirects to work (there can be some redirects using JavaScript instead of just proper HTML 3xx code). I can't make it work. I don't even need to load the content - I just have to make a hit there, so the server can count the page was loaded.

I've already tried WebClient:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0)";
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(myUrl), wc);
```

as well as HttpWebRequest:

```
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
```

but both of them get only to first page.

I also tried using "hiden" WebBrowser:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
wb.IsScriptEnabled = true;
wb.Navigate(myUri);
```

but it doesn't even get to the first page.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do that with WebClient or HttpWebRequest (since they don't understand Javascript), but the WebBrowser should work (I'm already doing that in one of my apps). Just make sure to add it to your page (even if hidden), and call the `Navigate` method from the UI thread.